# Unable to make entire LI item clickable

Tags: html, css

I have seen a few topics on this on StackOverflow and have tried to implement the tips in the posts but with no luck so this post is not intended to be duplicated, I am trying to make my entire LI link clickable, I have set up a JSFiddle and some code below. Thank you in advance for your help.

JSFiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/szfdh/

```
          <div class="menu" id="menubar"> <div class="w_960"><ul>

<li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-53 current_page_item menu-item-55"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="#">Junior Scheme</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="#">Teen Scheme</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="">Policies</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div><!-- end  menubar w_960 --> </div><!-- end menubar -->
```

Comment: This is because the link is around the text only. If you want to style your links as you do, it'd be better to just use the links instead of using a list. (Or that is at least how I do it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is a positioning property on the `a` element. [**See fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/szfdh/1/):

```
.menu li a {
   position: relative;
}
```

Your `z-index: 500` on the `a` is not being recognized because you did not give the `a` element positioning of any kind, and `z-index` is only for positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could either place an `onclick` event on the `li` tag or use CSS to make the `a` tags fill the `li`.  The latter solution is possible by setting `display:block;` on the `a` tag and then setting the height and other styling appropriately for the `li` tag.

Also, `li` tags are meant to be used for lists. Though in your full solution they might be used properly, in your example simply the `a` tags could suffice.

Comment: +1 for the second solution; for a menu in context of the question. Awesome.